# Best way to replace If-else in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a search option in my website with 4 searching criteria and it is not compulsory to enter all of those to search . I want to implement this logic in my data layer more specifically my stored procedure. One such approach is

```
if ( all four are empty)
select command
else if ( 3 are empty
select command
and so on...
```

Is there any other way where i can replace these IF statements with some better logic. In short i would like the search to be made only based on the values provided by user

Comment: it depends of your query. If it's simple, then this if-else logic is ok

Comment: Presumably you are using a web scripting language to take the input from the website and make the sql query.  Why not handle this in your script, rather than in SQL?

Comment: I am using LINQ in .net to call the stored procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or later, aside from very few unpatched installations at specific service packs and hotfix levels, this pattern will give you the best performance.

```
select ...
  from ...
 where (@criteria1 is null or column1 = @criteria1)
   and (@criteria2 is null or column2 = @criteria2)
       option (recompile)
```

Best reference for this type of dynamic criteria query writing is by Erland Sommarskog [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

If you can present only the filters requires by dynamically generating the query from the front-end, you'll achieve better results than this pattern for SQL Server 2005, although it's still the best option if dynamic SQL is not possible.

Comment: This should perhaps say "If you're using SQL Server 2008 or later". This method isn't optimal for SQL 2005 - see Sommarskog's article on 2005 - http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#AND_ISNOTNULL

Comment: no, you linked to another page which refers to that one. See http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#OR_ISNULL and compare it to http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#AND_ISNOTNULL

Comment: And the article you link to says 2008 with certain patching or later, not 2005 with certain patching or later.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi - the link in your answer - there are two pages linked two from it - one for 2008 with certain patches and later, and the other for 2005 and earlier (and 2008 without patches) It's only for the 2008 with certain patches and later one where `RECOMPILE` is the recommended approach.

Comment: @EDHarper AND_ISNOTNULL is not an option unless ONLY one criteria will ever be chosen. Clearly OP counts down from 4. OPTION RECOMPILE while not as good as dynamic SQL is the best single-query option.

Comment: @Damien Erland doesn't make a recommendation. From your reading, what's best for 2005?

Comment: As my query only had to check 4 options therefore i used dynamic query building with 4 if conditions to do the work . Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi   but i would like to see how your solution works once the answer is finalized and i am using sql server 2005

Answer (score 1):

You can use case logic:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN  all four are empty THEN expression
      WHEN 3 are empty THEN expression 
   END 
FROM ...
```

See details here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: -1 The "command" *IS* a select statement, not a column/expression.

Comment: You are right ! I used it because ffayyaz used it in his question. I will edit my answer. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Create base query and based on 4 input values append in where clause dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something as follows

```
Create sp datasearch
(
@param1 datatype=null,
@param2 datatype=null,
@param3 datatype=null,
@param4 datatype=null
)
as

select * from table where 
col1=isnull(@param1 ,col1) and 
col2=isnull(@param2 ,col2) and 
col3=isnull(@param3 ,col3) and 
col4=isnull(@param4 ,col4) and
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this kind of search also requires a ranking - a record where 4 of the criteria are matched is more important than a record where one is matched.

I haven't got access to a database right now, so the syntax below might be a bit broken, but in principle:

```
select ID, column1, column2, column3, column4, count(*) as rank
from 
(select ID, column1, column2, column3, column4
from searchtable
where column1 = @criteria1
union
select ID, column1, column2, column3, column4
from searchtable
where column2 = @criteria2
union
select ID, column1, column2, column3, column4
from searchtable
where column3 = @criteria3
union
select ID, column1, column2, column3, column4
from searchtable
where column4 = @criteria4)
group by select ID, column1, column2, column3, column4
order by rank desc
```

Comment: Yes i would want that  search shall include all the columns whose values are given by user